# How to get unique values from pandas series using aggregate method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider this `dataframe`

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(0,100,size=(200, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = list(numpy.arange(1001, 1021)) * 10
df['F'] = ['c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd'] * 20 + ['d', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'] * 20
```

I want to group by column 'E', but I want to aggregate some functions. For example `sum` values from column A, B, D and `count` column C. With column 'F' I want to get unique values in an array.

So I tried:

```
params = {
  'A': 'sum',
  'B': 'sum',
  'C': 'count',
  'D': 'sum',
  'F': pandas.Series.unique
}
df_ = df.groupby('E').agg(params).reset_index()
```

Which returns an Error: `Exception: Must produce aggregated value`

I tried this code because in another example it works. Since then, I have been trying the same method to filter different data, but without results.

If I use `pandas.Series.nunique` or `lambda x: x.nunique()` it counts unique values and it works ok. But, how can I get unique values using pandas `aggregate` method?

To get this work, I wrote a function with a `for loop` that takes a column name as a parameter. However, I hope this could have a better approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Error:

This happens because `pandas.Series.unique` returns an array of the unique values, which `agg` interprets as an attempt to broadcast different values to different rows and so rejects. You'd get the same error with a function that returns a pandas `Series` or `Index`.

### Solution:

If you pass the function you use later, `pandas.Series.nunique`,

```
params = {
  'A': 'sum',
  'B': 'sum',
  'C': 'count',
  'D': 'sum',
  'F': pd.Series.nunique
}

df.groupby('E').agg(params).reset_index()
Out[69]: 
       E   C  F    A    B    D
0   1001  10  2  500  463  595
1   1002  10  2  484  493  348
2   1003  10  1  507  400  479
...
17  1018  10  1  606  454  410
18  1019  10  2  537  522  724
19  1020  10  2  541  532  486
```

it should work fine.

If you want the unique values themselves, you can feed a lambda function to `agg`, as long as it recognizes the return value as an aggregated value/not a `Series`, `Index`, `np.ndarray`, or a subclass.

Ex:

```
params = {
  'A': 'sum',
  'B': 'sum',
  'C': 'count',
  'D': 'sum',
  'F': lambda x: ','.join(sorted(pd.Series.unique(x)))
}

df.groupby('E').agg(params).reset_index()
Out[82]: 
       E   C    F    A    B    D
0   1001  10  c,d  500  463  595
1   1002  10  a,b  484  493  348
2   1003  10    b  507  400  479
...
17  1018  10    b  606  454  410
18  1019  10  a,b  537  522  724
19  1020  10  c,d  541  532  486
```

Or, to be a bit silly:

```
params = {
  'A': 'sum',
  'B': 'sum',
  'C': 'count',
  'D': 'sum',
  'F': lambda x: pd.DataFrame(pd.Series.unique(x))
}

df.groupby('E').agg(params).reset_index()
Out[92]: 
       E   C     F    A    B    D
0   1001  10     0
              0  c
              1  d  500  463  595
1   1002  10     0
              0  b
              1  a  484  493  348
2   1003  10     0
              0  b  507  400  479
...
17  1018  10     0
              0  b  606  454  410
18  1019  10     0
              0  a
              1  b  537  522  724
19  1020  10     0
              0  d
              1  c  541  532  486
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 7):

Just change your function for `'F'` in `params`:

```
params = {
  'A': 'sum',
  'B': 'sum',
  'C': 'count',
  'D': 'sum',
  'F': (lambda x: list(x.unique()))
}
df_ = df.groupby('E').agg(params).reset_index()
```